# Android: border color GridView. No background

Tags: android, gridview, colors, background, border

I created an application with a GridView and I managed to change the color of all images with background (). But what I want is to put a red border to each image, with a space between them. Also change the color to green when you click on an image. As I can do? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your res/drawable add a file eg. border.xml and put something like that in there:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
  <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
  <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

Than use:  android:background="@drawable/border" in your layout file.

Comment: your code is background to all gridview. but thanks. i want a border in image, no background

Comment: So how do you fill your grid? Are you using an adapter?

Comment: yes, i am using an adapter. Do you need to see my code?

Comment: What I did is, I wrote my own adapter, to which I could add a layout file that is rendered for each element in the grid and in this layout file you can set the background to your border.xml. Here is an example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/ Look at 2.2

Comment: You can put your code where you do that please?

Comment: Is that tutorial helpful? If you still have questions feel free to ask.

Comment: I think so. Now I'm trying other things, but when finished i try your example. if I have questions or errors i ask you. thanks again